# Replacing lots of text with a string from the same line in one file

Tags: notepad++, regex, string

I have this:

```
TEXT_CONNECTED "You're connected."
TEXT_DISCONNECTED "You're disconnected."
```

and many more.

TEXT_CONNECTED and TEXT_DISCONNECTED are also used elsewhere in the same file, like:

```
SendMessage(TEXT_CONNECTED);
SendMessage(TEXT_DISCONNECTED);
```

I want to replace TEXT_CONNECTED with the string from the same line "You're connected.",
also the other one TEXT_DISCONNECTED with "You're disconnected."

So it will look like:

```
"You're connected." "You're connected."
"You're disconnected." "You're disconnected."
```

and

```
SendMessage("You're connected.");
SendMessage("You're disconnected.");
```

I'm using Notepad++, maybe this can be done with regex?

Comment: It's impossible to do with a single regex,you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well what you want, it should be easy. Just open the file, select "Replace" in the menu bar, and in the window that will appear insert the text to be replaced and the replacement. Then, click "Replace all". Repeat this for all different strings to be replaced. and voila, you're done! :-)

Comment: It's not “easy”, it's impossible to do with a single regex, have you tried to do it? How many times it takes if you have hundred strings to replace?